# Spring boot websocket test

Tags: testing, spring-boot, web, websocket, spring-test

I have a spring boot project with websocket and I want to test the project sending multiple request to the socket from different users. I want to use threads to imitate the users that send data from the web app but I don't know exactly how to make the test. Can anyone help me, and show one simple test for an websocket using threads?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***JMeter*** for testing your websocket project.

For further reading:

1. https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter
2. http://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring

Good example:

1. https://github.com/Fyro-Ing/JMeter-WebSocket-StompSampler

Answer (score 0):

When writing a Spring Boot application using STOMP on websockets, I struggled a lot to find out how to configure a test client.

I ended up writing a [little library called Jackstomp](https://github.com/joffrey-bion/jackstomp) to make it easier to create type-safe tests for STOMP WS applications using JSON as message body.

I haven't used it with multiple threads, but you should be able to easily use it within each thread to create independent clients for each user and perform basic operations. (Please note that a different client should be used in each thread).

The point is that you can really express a synchronous flow for each client, including actively querying for received events.

Even if you don't use this library, you can look at the code to get a grasp of the different things to setup.